'Who' is 'suffering'?

"What do you think, Anuradha: Do you regard form as the Tathagata?"
"No, lord."
"Do you regard feeling as the Tathagata?"
"No, lord."
"Do you regard perception as the Tathagata?"
"No, lord."
"Do you regard fabrications as the Tathagata?"
"No, lord."
"Do you regard consciousness as the Tathagata?"
"No, lord."
"What do you think, Anuradha: Do you regard the Tathagata as being in form?... Elsewhere than form?... In feeling?... Elsewhere than
feeling?... In perception?... Elsewhere than perception?... In
fabrications?... Elsewhere than fabrications?... In consciousness?...
Elsewhere than consciousness?"
"No, lord."
"What do you think: Do you regard the Tathagata as form-feeling-perception-fabrications-consciousness?"
"No, lord."
"Do you regard the Tathagata as that which is without form, without feeling, without perception, without fabrications, without
consciousness?"
"No, lord."
"And so, Anuradha — when you can't pin down the Tathagata as a truth or reality even in the present life — is it proper for you to
declare, 'Friends, the Tathagata — the supreme man, the superlative
man, attainer of the superlative attainment — being described, is
described otherwise than with these four positions: The Tathagata
exists after death, does not exist after death, both does & does not
exist after death, neither exists nor does not exist after death'?"
"No, lord."
"Very good, Anuradha. Very good. Both formerly & now, it is only suffering that I describe, and the cessation of suffering."

Based on the above, who is it that is really suffering? And who is I?

The Tathagata does not suffer therefore the quote appears not relevant to the question asked here.

@DhammaDhatu perhaps you can explain more why the quote is irrelevant in the context of the question in your answer.

“The self is just the mental idea of "I am". The self idea arises from moment to moment, from the mind-body phenomena, depending on conditions. It's always changing, just as the five aggregates are always changing.”

We are karma made, karma borned and karma evolved. All that we are, is the result of past and current actions (karma).
who is it that is really suffering?

“‘I am subject to aging, have not gone beyond aging.’ This is the first fact that one should reflect on often....


“‘I am subject to illness, have not gone beyond illness’....


“‘I am subject to death, have not gone beyond death’....


“‘I will grow different, separate from all that is dear & appealing to me’....


“‘I am the owner of actions [kamma], heir to actions, born of actions, related through actions, and have actions as my arbitrator. Whatever I do, for good or for evil, to that will I fall heir’....

The Buddha stated clearly as well in AN5:57. The part that we struggled so much with is the stubborn insistence that there is something permanent, constant, unchanging and indestructible within our self. This is especially hard for non-Buddhists.
For Buddhists, this is not a big deal because from the moment they learned the Dharma, they already knew that it is anicca, anatta and dukkha i.e. everything changes and we have no absolute control therefore suffering exists.
Our personality, character, likes, dislikes, preferences, physical attributes, wealth, our way of thinking and everything that is internal or external, physical and non-physical about us are all karma made.
When I first realized this, it was very liberating at the beginning then it turned disheartening and disappointing. But after a while it became very inspiring again. There was deep disappointment initially because it means there is nothing special and unique about ourselves or anyone. Later, it became very inspiring because I realize that by doing good deeds and being virtuous one can spread a lot of happiness to ourselves and others. At the end of the day, this is what really matters if we are stuck in samsara. It’s not the karmic results of good looks, health, wealth, power or fame that matters but the happiness we achieve for ourselves and others.
But even the happiness arising from good karma does not endure. Realizing that the Buddha declared a happiness that is far superior than any good karma, is the greatest inspiration.

Addendum
(Below is added in response to observed queries)
An individual presumes he has an identity
There is a process of cause and effect that leads to the formation of an identity-view. It is not a figment of our imagination. Desire is the foundation that give rise eventually to this self-concept. As this answer alluded, the unenlightened mind cannot help but interject inputs into the direct experience (reality that is vs reality that the mind wants, think and feel ought to be). The emphasis or weightage is shifted from the experience to the experiencer when they inject their desires, preferences, likes or dislikes and other strange storylines into the experiencing. When this happens the line between experience and experiencer is blurred. The audience is now pulled into the movie (i.e. the direct experiencing) and become the actors totally consumed and acting out their assigned roles. We become the hero, the villain, the jealous wife, the unfaithful husband and so on.
presumes that suffering that is arising is himself/herself because it is disturbing his preconceived notion of his/her state whatever it was prior to suffering
Prior state that can be changed is suffering. Anything that is inconstant will eventually leads to suffering. It is precisely because of this, the search for something that is indestructible, unchanging, eternal and forever lasting is so important in Buddhism. Finding this Constant/Eternal/Indestructible element or state is the equivalent to the end of suffering (i.e. Nirvana) as per my understanding in the Dharma. Unfortunately, this state or element cannot be found in a 'self' or any 'self'. Because the self-identity is created; a result of cause and effect.
There is no 'I' in anywhere to be find neither in mind nor body, its only suffering that arises and ceases to exist in various forms and degrees, is my understanding correct?
The only way to find out is when we are in great pain and suffering and we try to console ourselves that there is no 'I' anywhere to be found. See if it brings comfort and peace. If it does then the understanding is there. If not, there is more work to be done.
And so whatever decisions or choices a person takes in daily life, is it only because he is reacting to circumstances, both mental or physical?
As long as we are alive, we are constantly reacting. The question is whether there is the presence of cravings, aversions and delusions in our reactions. If they are absent, we can do a lot of things and not suffer. When they are present even doing nothing, we will still suffer.
With Metta.

@NithinManmohan I added some answers w.r.t your queries.

@ Desmon, Thanks for taking time and clarifying. My articulation is often poor, but your response really was clear and crystal. Metta.

May we all be free from sufferings. ☺️

When the Buddha declared freedom from suffering, he declared it was the mind (citta/ceto) that was liberated. For example:

Visaṅkhāragataṁ cittaṁ taṇhānaṁ khayamajjhagā
My mind has reached the Unconditioned; has reached the destruction
of craving.
Dhp 154


The goal, heartwood and final end of the spiritual life is the
unshakable freedom of mind.
Yā ca kho ayaṁ, bhikkhave, akuppā cetovimutti— etadatthamidaṁ,
bhikkhave, brahmacariyaṁ, etaṁ sāraṁ etaṁ pariyosāna.
MN 29

Therefore, what suffers is the mind.
HOWEVER, when suffering afflicts the mind, this suffering is dependent upon the delusion of self-view or self-identity, which is part of the affliction upon the mind.
The question of "who" is an inappropriate question in supramundane Buddhism. Refer to SN 12.12 and SN 12.17.

So, there is no individual or sufferer, but only suffering that arises. An individual presumes he has an identity and presumes that suffering that is arising is himself/herself because it is disturbing his preconceived notion of his/her state whatever it was prior to suffering(in other words, the individual is experiencing change). There is no 'I' in anywhere to be find neither in mind nor body, its only suffering that arises and ceases to exist in various forms and degrees, is my understanding correct?

And so whatever decisions or choices a person takes in daily life, is it only because he is reacting to circumstances, both mental or physical?

I added to the answer

Who suffers ? Is an invalid question.
Suffering is bound to arise because of the cravings. Who craves ? Is an invalid question.
Suffering can be put to an end.
The path leading to the end of suffering is Nobel 8 fold path.
A more detailed explanation of origin of suffering is dependent origination, which is as follows:
Given ignorance as condition sanskharas arise. Given sanskaras, consciousness arise. Given consciousness, six senses arise. Given six senses , contact arises. Given contact, feelings arise. Given feelings , cravings arise. Given cravings, clinging arise. Given clinging becoming arise. Given becoming birth arises. Given birth , ageing and death and whole mass of suffering arises.
Notice that nowhere we say who suffers or who craves because that does not apply.
Suffering is a Sankhara. Meaning it is a conditioned phenomena. It is a result of combination and conditions. For example when body , consciousness and disease combine conditionally suffering arises.

Who suffers? Not a valid question.

“Venerable sir, who feels?”
“Not a valid question,” the Blessed One replied. “I do not say, ‘One
feels.’ If I should say, ‘One feels,’ in that case this would be a
valid question: ‘Venerable sir, who feels?’ But I do not speak thus.
Since I do not speak thus, if one should ask me, ‘Venerable sir, with
what as condition does feeling come to be?’ this would be a valid
question. To this the valid answer is: ‘With contact as condition,
feeling comes to be; with feeling as condition, craving.’”
“Venerable sir, who craves?”
“Not a valid question,” the Blessed One replied. “I do not say, ‘One
craves.’ If I should say, ‘One craves,’ in that case this would be a
valid question: ‘Venerable sir, who craves?’ But I do not speak thus.
Since I do not speak thus, if one should ask me, ‘Venerable sir, with
what as condition does craving come to be?’ this would be a valid
question. To this the valid answer is: ‘With feeling as condition,
craving comes to be; with craving as condition, clinging; with
clinging as condition, existence…. Such is the origin of this whole
mass of suffering.’
SN 12.12

Who is I?
"I" (self) is an illusionary self, a thought constructed by the mind, as implied by the notion “I am the thinker” from Snp 4.14 and birth (jati) of dependent origination.

In the Ananda Sutta, the Buddha did not answer when Vacchagotta asked if there was a self, or no self. The reason he gave to Ananda for this was that it would only confuse Vacchagotta, by making him appear to either (a) identify with the idea of an eternal soul or (b) identify with a nihilistic view of reality and the self.
In terms of what the Buddha actually taught I will defer to Thanissaro Bhikkhu here, who states that the later Buddhist views (that there is a sense of self that comes into being through aggregation of the 5 aggregates) are not in keeping with scripture, and that the Buddha focussed on the cause of suffering - clinging - and that clinging to a sense of self is an impediment to enlightenment. Likewise, clinging to an idea of 'no-self' can be an impediment at later stages of the path.
It is not that a sense of self is unimportant, it is that it is not the goal. It comes into being through causes and conditions. It can be improved, and improving it can be a skillful means to aid path progression. But it is not the goal.

I is a feeling which get fabricated due to causes. And when the I is in action I is suffering by emitting more energy at the end of each thoughts (minds)
Let's assume an environment which is only lacking factor to start a fire is Oxygen. All the other factors are there.
So when Oxygen is present, suddenly a fire started in the environment.
Now what happened. Is someone got burned? No. When all the causes are present it resulted in something. In this case a fire started.
Similarly, when all the things are in order a mind (a thought) get started (in a fraction of a second) And since the energy stored in the universe which was generated by previous minds is also there, this mind is fabricating an existence which feels like "I"

Allow me to untangle a knot, here…
The question "Who is suffering?" leads us in the wrong direction. The better question is this: "What has come into existence in order to suffer?". Think of it like this:

We have experiences
Some experiences feel good, some feel bad, some are indifferent…
We find we prefer the good experiences to the indifferent, and the indifferent to the bad. This makes us discontent (the beginnings of dukkha)
We make efforts reach for the good experiences and avoid the bad. This leads to urges, aversions, cravings, etc (the beginnings of tanhā)
We create a mental 'subject' that has the task of anticipating, planning, fighting for and against, manipulating, securing, lying about and telling the truth, etc: whatever is needed to satisfy those aversions and cravings, so as to relieve that discontentment (the beginnings of a self)

This constructed 'subject' (self) is created specifically to address issues that can lead to suffering. When we forget who we are and take this constructed self is an identity, then we start to take its issues on as matters of (utmost) self-importance, and that leads to suffering. But when we remember that this self was something constructed to solve issues — not to create suffering — then its tasks are no longer matters of utmost importance to us, and suffering dissolves into mere problem-solving.
So who is suffering? Only those who haven't remembered who they are.

The sense of self is very real and is what we refer to as "I".  This is undeniable.
Anyone that proposes otherwise makes a fool of themself.
Pun completely intended.

Who is saying self doesn’t exist ?
